# Is it possible to export a graph as graphic to Excel?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, export, excel

It is straightforward to export lists to Excel with `Export`. Can I export a graphic image, too? This does not work:

```
g = CompleteGraph[4];
fnOut = "Output1.xls";
Export[fnOut, {"Sheet1" -> g}]
```

Maybe I need to transform `g` in some way?

Comment: What do you want to see in Excel? An image or a Plot?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is. I do not need details of the graphs such as coordinates of the vertices. And I do not need Excel's graphing capabilities. So, image, I suppose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can export both data and the images using one of several syntax patterns that you find in the [docs on XLS format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLS.html):

[image]
[image]

For example:

```
 g = CompleteGraph[7];
 Export["output1.xls", 
 {g, {"mySheet1" -> Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[g]}}, {{"Images", "Sheets"}}]
```

gives

[image]

**EDIT: Exporting multiple images:**

It seems you need at least one sheet (which could be empty) as part of any export. With this restriction,

```
Export["multipleImages.xls", {CompleteGraph[#] & /@ {5, 7, 9}, {}},
  {{"Images", "Sheets"}}]
```

or

```
Export["multipleImages2.xls", {{}}, "Images" -> (CompleteGraph[#] & /@ {5, 7, 9})]
```

or

```
Export["multipleImages3.xls", 
  {"Sheets" -> {}, "Images" -> (CompleteGraph[#] & /@ {5, 7, 9})}, "Rules"]
```

all work to export several images.

Comment: this is very helpful. Do you have an advice how to export several graphs in one `Export` statement? I studied the docs, but can not figure this out.

Comment: @Karsten, I was not able to export only images (without at least one sheet accompanying the images), it seems you need at least one sheet (which could be empty) as part of any export. So, `Export["multipleImages.xls", {CompleteGraph[#] & /@ {5, 7, 9}, {}}, {{"Images", "Sheets"}}]` or `Export["multipleImages2.xls", {{}}, "Images" -> (CompleteGraph[#] & /@ {5, 7, 9})]` both work to export several graphs.

Comment: Great! I will try on Monday.

Comment: aaaaand that puts you to 10k! Let the party begin! We now have 10 10k users

Comment: @R.M Thank you again!

Comment: I tried :  Export["output1.xls", 
 {g, {"mySheet1" -> Normal@AdjacencyMatrix[g]}}, {{"Images", "Sheets"}}] and I got an error message : Java::argxs: The static method System`Convert`ExcelDump`write was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. Can anybody help me on that ?

Answer (score 6):

If you need a basic data behind the graph, the `AdjacencyMatrix` I think is good for tabular formats. This will work:

```
 Export["graph_data.xls", AdjacencyMatrix[CompleteGraph[13]]]
```

> "graph_data.xls"

If you need the image of the graph object, in addition to programmatic way (see @kguler answer) there is an interactive way I personally use often. The steps (on win7):

- Right click on a graph to copy it

[image]

- In MS Excel open a drop-down under **Paste**, choose **Paste Special** and then choose **Picture**

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The o/p clearly wanted to Export a graphic image to .xls, not manually import an image from Excel. And kguler's reply clearly proves the statement "... then you should export it as an image" wrong. I'd almost downvote.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Yes kguler answer is cool, I updated my answer due to it. Nevertheless the interactive way I describe is something people often do not know. Some can benefit, as I did when I learned it.

Comment: An addition: the quality of EMF graphics always depends on the size on screen of the original image because metafiles are sampled at screen resolution fidelity (see my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3391/280)).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov True. The easiest way is to drag the outer image frame to larger size if one does everything with the mouse anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I want to export several graphs in one `Export` statement.