# How do I format an Exported plot to Excel?

Tags: export, excel

I have the following piece of code:

```
Plot[StateResponse[
   nss,
   {0.01 UnitStep[t - tstep], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {t, 0, tstop}] // Evaluate,
 {t, 0, tstop} ,
 PlotLabel -> "State Variable Open loop response to 1% step in Dd"]
```

which gives me a five variable plot.

I want to export this plot to excel to compare with some other data but can't get `Export` to format the exported *Mathematica* data as I want, i.e. in six columns.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica! Hello dhog and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. It is always best to include a minimal, working example in your question. Users can then copy/paste/try your code and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I've a big matrices that needs to be plotted as part of the StateResponse command but I can't copy it in without loosing the Mathematica formatting, is it possible to enter it somehow?

Comment: is [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7932/125) relevant/useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we define your parameters as:

```
 tstep = .5;
 tstop = 10;
 nss = StateSpaceModel[{
     {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {5.3572, 7.602, 56.6571,18.102}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-5.3572, -7.602, -46.8571, -18.102}}, 
      {{0}, {0.5}, {0}, \{-0.5}}}, 
       SamplingPeriod -> None, SystemsModelLabels -> None];
```

Then store the response as a list:

```
 response = Table[Evaluate@StateResponse[nss, 
                    {0.01 UnitStep[t - tstep], 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {t, 0, tstop}], {t, 0, tstop, .1}];
 ListPlot[Transpose@response,
          PlotLabel -> "State Variable Open loop response to 1% step in Dd", 
          Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Which can be exported to xls and plotted in Excel

```
 Export["temp.xls",response]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! This was exactly what I wanted!