# How to export data to Excel with images within cells?

Tags: export, excel, office

How can I export data along with images into Excel, with the images inserted into cells as shown below?

[image]

```
data = {{1, CompleteGraph[3], CompleteGraph[4], 
    CompleteGraph[5]}, {2, CompleteGraph[6], CompleteGraph[7], 
    CompleteGraph[8]}};
Export["multipleImages.xls", data]
```

Comment: Does Excel now support images embedded in spreadsheet cells? That didn't use to be possible.

Comment: An old [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/is-it-possible-to-export-a-graph-as-graphic-to-excel) ; not sure if it related to the task at hand.

Comment: @MarcoB You're probably right; it doesn't seem to support this feature.
Actually, I want to place them into cells so that when I  filter data, the image on that row also filtered.

Comment: @Syed I saw that but it exports images to different sheets instead.

Comment: This [page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/insert-picture-excel-cell/#:~:text=Paste%20picture%20in%20Excel%20from%20another%20program&text=Select%20an%20image%20in%20another,Yep%2C%20it's%20that%20easy!) suggests that it is possible for newer versions. Unfortunately mine is from 2013.

Comment: who needs Excel  when you have Mathematica? :)

Comment: People doing accounting may need a Spreadsheet like Excel, everybody else using Excel is most likely using the *wrong tool*.

Comment: @Nasser There are two reasons for that.
The first reason is that Excel is more commonly used and easier to share, in my opinion. And I also think that using data filtering is probably easier for them on Excel.

Comment: I want to export a large amount of data, like 100k rows to Excel or something common so people can do the filtering anyway that they like.

Comment: @internet If the idea is to use something common so people can access it, why not use an Open Standard file format like `"XML"`, `"JSON"` or `"CSV"` instead of a closed format from proprietary software?

Comment: @rhermans 
That is because I'm not familiar with them. Also the data contains images.

Comment: @internet you could embed files and images in a CSV with `{3, ExportString[CompleteGraph[3], {"Base64", "GXL"}], ExportString[CompleteGraph[3], {"Base64", "PNG"}]}`. Also, `"HTML"` could be another Open Standard file format.

Comment: @rhermans `Export["file.csv", {3, 
  ExportString[CompleteGraph[3], {"Base64", "GXL"}], 
  ExportString[CompleteGraph[3], {"Base64", "PNG"}]}, "CSV"]`
Is this correct?
It's not working for me. The ExportString function is returning a wall of text instead of images.
One of the reasons I like Excel is that you can apply filters in any way you want (although not on images).

Comment: The files are encoded. How do you expect the people consuming your data to use it?

Comment: @rhermans I want to display these graphs as images, purely for the purpose of providing extra information. For instance, let's take a single row from a pool of 100,000 rows, which could be structured like this: `{1, data1, data2, data3, image}`. Here, `data1, data2, and data3` hold the filtering data that users can employ. Depending on the conditions applied to `data1, data2, and data3`, the row might either be retained or removed, but the image will always be associated with the row.

Answer (score 3):

JLink helps for your simple example.
I tested the code below on Windows and Linux. Seems to work just fine.
However, I doubt using JLink will work reasonably fast for really big data, maybe with parallelization.
Or you may want to resort to NETLink then.
Or use a Python solution and call this from Mathematica.

```
Needs["JLink`"];

    checkType[val_Image]:=True;
    checkType[val_?NumberQ]:=True;
    checkType[val_String]:=True;
    checkType[_]=False;

ExcelExport[xlsFile_String, data:{ {__?checkType}.. }, rowHeight_:40] := 
  Module[{wb, sheet, writeCell}, 
    JLink`JavaBlock[JLink`LoadJavaClass["org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor"];
    wb = JLink`JavaNew["org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook"];
     sheet = If[wb@getNumberOfSheets[] > 0, 
            wb@getSheetAt[0]
            ,
            wb@createSheet[$Version]
       ];
      
     writeCell[noImg_?NumberQ, cell_, ___]:=cell @ setCellValue[noImg];
     writeCell[str_String, cell_]:=cell @ setCellValue[str];
     writeCell[img_Image, _, ri_Integer, ci_Integer]:= Block[{bytes, pictureId, drawing, myAnchor, myPicture},
         bytes = Normal @ ExportByteArray[img, "PNG"];
         pictureId = wb@addPicture[bytes, wb@PICTUREUTYPEUPNG];
         drawing = sheet@createDrawingPatriarch[];
         myAnchor = JLink`JavaNew["org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor"];
         myAnchor@setCol1[ci-1];
         myAnchor@setRow1[ri-1];  
         myPicture = drawing@createPicture[myAnchor, pictureId];
         myPicture@resize[]
     ];
      
       Do[ 
         row[r] = sheet@createRow[r - 1];
         row[r]@setHeightInPoints[rowHeight];
           Do[
             cell[r, c] = row[r]@createCell[c - 1];
             writeCell[data[[r, c]], cell[r, c], r, c]
           , {c, Dimensions[data][[2]]}
           ]
         ,
         {r, Dimensions[data][[1]]}
         ];
         
         foutstream = JLink`JavaNew["java.io.FileOutputStream", xlsFile];
         wb@write[foutstream];
         foutstream @ close[];
         wb@close[];
         
    ];
         xlsFile
];
sq = ImageResize[Image[GraphPlot[#,PlotStyle->{Black,Thick},Background->LightBlue],ImageResolution->200], {100}]&;

data={{1,sq@CompleteGraph[3],sq@CompleteGraph[4],sq@CompleteGraph[5]},
      {2,sq@CompleteGraph[6],sq@CompleteGraph[7],sq@CompleteGraph[8]}};
test = ExcelExport["test.xlsx",data];
SystemOpen @ test
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Export as HTML

Here I ignore the request in the title to use MS Excel, but focus on the statement in the comments, where the user needs to browse the data.

### HTML templates with `StringTemplate`

```
bodywrap = StringTemplate@"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Avoid using Excel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>``</div>
  </body>
</html>";

downloadLink = StringTemplate@"<a href=\"data:file/glx;base64,`1`\" download=\"`2`\">`3`</a>";
```

### Export file and open

```
Export["test.html", 
  bodywrap@ExportString[
    TableForm@Table[
      {
       k,
       Rasterize[CompleteGraph[k]],
       downloadLink @@ {
         ExportString[CompleteGraph[k], {"Base64", "GXL"}],
         "Graph.GXL", "Download GXL File"
         }
       },
      {k, 3, 5}
      ], "HTMLFragment", ImageSize -> 100]
  , "String"] // SystemOpen
```

This will generate an `"HTML"` file (*HTML* is an *Open Standard* file format) with a table with images, data, and even files to download.

[image]

Images and files are embedded `"Base64"` encoded, not linked. I use two alternative solutions, one either using [`ExportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExportString.html)`[expr, {"Base64", "Format"}]` and a [`StringTemplate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html) and another using directly `ExportString[expr,`[`"HTMLFragment"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HTMLFragment.html)`]`

[image]

Comment: @internet Does this answer your needs? Or do you still want a solution based on Excel?