# What is the best way to make a plot complete with legends so it is exported-ready for Word?

Tags: plotting, export, office

I want to put my Plot output into an MS Word document without having to edit it in Corel first, so I want to export it ready for Word in vector format complete with legends, expressions, axes, and frames. Is it possible to do that in *Mathematica* 9? After getting `Plot` output, what procedure should I follow to put it into Word?

I want the best quality figures in my Word document with thin colored lines. Here is example of what I to do when I have many curves on one plot, using dashed and dotdashed combination.

```
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], 1/x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

I look forward to seeing your examples of multi-curve plots that are Word export-ready.

Comment: Try exporting as [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), `Export[filename, plot, "SVG"]`

Comment: @ssch do you have answer with more details, figure should be ready and clear for word, similar with figures from origin or excel.

Comment: If you use `Export["file.pdf", plot]`, doesn't inserting the PDF in Word work?  (You can also select the output cell and use the menu command "Save Selection as...".)

Comment: @ Michael I need full quality to put first in word doc to set positions of several figures and then export with text. More detail and professional answer is required.

Comment: @Pipe, I have neither Word nor Mathematica 9, so no.

Comment: A related question may be [How can I ensure graphics exported in WMF format don't have text-spacing problems?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92/245)

Comment: @Jens Now when I have .svg or other formats (which format you prefer) file to import in vector form into word document?

Comment: @ssch Word does not support importing vector graphics in SVG format.

Comment: @Oleksandr so what to do with figure, how to import it in best quality into word document

Comment: @Pipe just save the graphic as EMF. You might like to outline the text first, though, as described by [Jens](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4387/) and [Alexey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124065).

Comment: @Oleksandr Thank you very much all of you (Jens, Alexey,m_goldberg,yohbs,Ernst Stelzer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in Legend package is really bad. A good alternative is `legendMaker` and is fully documented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/creating-legends-for-plots-with-multiple-lines/4036#4036). Assuming you loaded this package, you can use this code, from your example:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], 1/x}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"x", "f(x)"})]
labels = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Sin[3 x], Sin[4 x], Superscript[x, -1]};
opts = Sequence[Background -> LightOrange, RoundingRadius -> 10];
newPlot = 
 Overlay[{plot, legendMaker[labels, opts]}, Alignment -> {0.8, 0.9}]
```

The result is:
[image]

Having plotted everything you need, saving as `PDF` is easy - just use

```
Export["foo.pdf",plot]
```

The result is vector graphics with full quality and is scalable. You can then include the `PDF` file in your Word document, or better yet, in [$\LaTeX$](http://www.latex-project.org/).

Comment: something is wrong in the code? isn't it? I got something not very well.

Comment: thank you very much, but what I should do. First to run which code? Final in another post are f and g and when I want to apply mine, doesn't work?

Comment: How did you get last figure?

Comment: Glad to see that the `legendMaker` solution is still of use. Just when I was being asked to update it, version 9 came out with new `Legends` so I didn't improve it further. Another way to do it with the code in my answer is just one line: `autoLegend[plot, {Sin[x],Sin[2 x],Sin[3 x],Sin[4 x],Superscript[x,-1]}, Alignment -> {.5, .6}]` (the `Alignment` scales from `-1` to `1` in both directions). I can'te really post another answer because I don't have that thing called "word".

Comment: Word does not support importing vector graphics in PDF format. EMF should be used instead.

Comment: @Jens how to export this 3d graphic from the further link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6124065#6124065

Answer (score 1):

Until now I have been unable to import vector graphics into a distributable Word file.  The first thing I do is decide on a specific style I use throughout a notebook, e.g.

```
opts = BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Times", Italic};
```

Then I simply save the plots with code such as

```
image = Show[graph, ImageSize -> 1024]; Export[name, image, "JPEG"]
```

and insert the JPG-image into the Word file.  You would have to make sure that the size of your PlotLegends etc. fit the image size.  The results are usually more than reasonably good.  However, I usually go through several rounds of adaptations until I am satisfied.

Comment: @Stelzer Thank you for your answer, can you share your experience with steps until the figure is ready for word and then further for pdf file?

Comment: Are you using origin, corel or excel for adaptations?

Comment: +1 But you should PNG not JPG. JPG is for photographs. (JPEG stands for joint photographic experts group). See this Wiki link for quality comparison: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Comparison_to_JPEG

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I agree about `PNG` - but I recall ten years ago (the last time I used "word") there was also `WMF` which looked promising. If this still exists it may be closer to `PDF`...

Comment: @Jens - since a few years ago differences in the MS and Wolfram metafile standards causes WMF curves to alias. PNGs exported at high `ImageResolution` import nicely into Word. I will have to check out the PDF suggestion.

Comment: @Jens WMF is obsolete format. It is replaced by EMF which gives much better results especially when dealing with non-ASCII characters. The EMF export is supported by *Mathematica*. This format is the native vector graphics format of Microsoft Office.