# Some Characters From Custom Font Do Not Show Up

Tags: formatting, text, symbols, fonts, style

I'm using version 8.0.4.0 on a Mac, and recently made my own .otf and .ttf fonts at [PaintFont.com](http://www.PaintFont.com).  The font can be based on pretty much anything, including handwriting, and covers everything from alpha-numerics, symbols, alphabets from other languages, punctuation, and ligatures.  This can be very useful if you want your figures and text to look a little more personalized.

The good news is, when I use something like:

```
Text[Style["This is the text I want in a different font.", FontFamily->"Example Font"]]
```

basic alpha-numerics, capitals and lowercase, work just fine, but certain symbols, including ! @ # % ^ * ( ) ~ - = + [ ] { } ; : | < >, Greeks, and so forth, show up simply in Mathematica's default font, even though I have characters for my font that definitely work (I've tested them in Word, etc.).

Just an example, if I type:

```
Text[\[CapitalSigma]]
```

I get a capital sigma in **default font**, even though I definitely have that symbol in my own font.

Is there any reason why Mathematica would accept certain characters from a font and not others?  Are these characters "reserved" somehow by Mathematica and are "unformatable"?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about fonts myself but it would probably help if you could link to a font that does show this problem (the fonts I tried work fine).

Comment: @Szabolcs Aside from my own font, I see that the punctuation and similar characters don't show up for Chicago, Times, Times New Roman, Helvetica, and Tahoma.  Perhaps something was not installed properly?  Would an image or screenshot comparing two different fonts work?

Comment: Many (if not all) of the characters you mention are termed "spanning characters".  In the Mathematica fonts they are represented by multiple glyphs.  Mathematica does this so that it can create typesetting effects like brackets that span the whole vertical dimension of 2D text.

Since this is an implementation detail, I do not think you can easily replace them in your own font.

Comment: @ChristopherCole Interesting, I can see how those reserved characters like {} [] and so forth might need to remain unchanged because they have functional purposes beyond simple text.  Given that when these characters are inside of quotations "", and therefore set to be rendered as text rather than functional characters, shouldn't that allow for them to be changed to the proper font?  I did notice that one could get the " or ' or , to work when a forward slash is put immediately before it.  Is there a similar convention that allows those remaining characters to be identified as only text?

Comment: Strongly relevant thread: "[How to avoid font substitution with *Mathematica* fonts?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18980/280)"

Comment: Also, I see that \[Copyright] works, even though that is a constructed symbol from (, C, and ), the first and last of which themselves do not work.  Very confusing.  @AlexeyPopkov I can't seem to find "OperatorSubstitution" anywhere in my help files, is this unique to version 9?

Comment: No, it should work in earlier versons. I cannot check right now but may be this option is undocumented. In any case the linked answer contains the most complete information on this option that is available.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I finally got it to work.  It took some tinkering, but it seems to properly accept all of the characters of the new font.  If you resubmit your comment and an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @iwantmyphd My comment cannot be considered as a self-contained answer. I think that it would be much more interesting and useful if you post extended answer yourself based on your experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alexey Popkov was right in his comment, see "How to avoid font substitution with Mathematica fonts?": https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18980/280

Even though in the Mathematica help files you may not find "OperatorSubstitution" anywhere, but if you add

```
BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}
```

within your code, this appears to fix it for any non-alphanumeric symbol you might have.

**EDIT:** This also appears to work with version 9.0.0-9.0.1.