# Getting Mathematica 9 to export text and axes of a plot as vector graphics in SVG

Tags: export, svg-format

Minimal working example:

```
Export["test.pdf", DensityPlot[1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]]
Export["test.svg", DensityPlot[1/(x^2 + y^2 + 1), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

The pdf has vector text (paths, I guess), but the svg file is very pixelated, and really just seems to be a png or some such imported into an empty svg file. How can I get Mathematica to output the axes and especially the labels as paths?

I've tried [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/exporting-mathematica-expression-as-svg) answer, which does the trick, but totally mangles the plot itself

Edit: Following Jens comment below, using `contourDensityPlot` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/245) worked fine for both pdf and svg formats, both for axes and labels and for the plot itself.

Comment: The failure of my linked answer seems to be a bug in `PDF` import. This bug doesn't appear in version 8, but I do see it in version 10.

Comment: Does it work if you use the function `contourDensityPlot` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/245)?

Comment: @Jens: Yes, it does! The contourDensityPlots look fine and vectory in both versions (btw, the contourRegionPlots do, too). What is the etiquette, here? Do I mark this as answer now, or does the bug (I guess) in Mathematica, and the fact that it's a workaround to something that should work out of the box, preclude a "answered" mark?

Comment: I think I'll write an answer now to propose the `contourDensityPlot` approach as a workaround... you application is not directly a duplicate, and there may be other answers as work-arounds to your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supposed to happen, but indeed the `SVG` output is rasterized. It happens when you use `DensityPlot`, but not with `ContourPlot` (in version 8 at least). So I think this is a bug. To keep the axes as vector graphics, I would suggest [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3196/245) as a work-around.